# Get by reflection properties of class attribute

Tags: reflection, c#-4.0, attributes

I find classes inherit from interface :

```
  var baseType = typeof(ICustomSerialization);
  Assembly assembly = baseType.Assembly;

   var subClass = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(baseType) );
```

If class have attribute and parameter Name:

```
    [CustomAttribute(Name="Soap")]
    class CustomSoapSerializer : ICustomSerialization
```

It is a way to get by reflection Name property of this attribute?

Comment: I'm confused by your wording.  So I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do.  However, if you're trying to get the attributes, you can use `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes`

Comment: If I get Attribute in Your way I have access to Name property ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
public static class CustomAttributeProviderExtensions
{
    public static TAttribute[] GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>(this ICustomAttributeProvider self)
        where TAttribute:Attribute
    {
        return (TAttribute[])self.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true);
    }
}
```

And the usage

```
var baseType = typeof(ICustomSerialization);
Assembly assembly = baseType.Assembly;

var subClass = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t))
    .Where(t=>t.GetCustomAttributes<CustomAttribute>().Any(x=>x.Name == "Soap"))
    .ToList();
```